# Multiple series in Highcharts with multiple drilldowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, highcharts

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kh5jY/) example, however I'm struggling to make it work with two series together.

I want to have two series, each of which are drilled down to two series when we drilldown on either of the parent series.

If I don't put in the drilldown categories for each point, I get only one series when I drill down.· If I add the drilldowns to each point as each series as the example suggests, I get nothing displayed.

```
        for cluster in models.Cluster.objects.all():
        qd = self.clone_query_dict()
        qd['cluster'] = cluster.id
        drilldown = {'categories': [x.name for x in get_countries().filter(
            client_clusters=cluster,
        )]}
        drilldown.update(self.drilldown_by_cluster(cluster))
        site_numbers_data.append(self.get_datum(
            qd,
            cluster.name,
            drilldown=drilldown,
        )
        avg_risk_data.append(self.get_datum(
            qd,
            cluster.name,
            drilldown=drilldown,
            avg='avg_field',
        ))
```

I'm constructing the JSON with Python:

```
for child in parent:
```

The code I'm templating off:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
        categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
        name = ['Browser brands'],
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    series: [{
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'MSIE versions 2000',
                        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                        color: colors[0]
                    },{
                        type: 'column',
                        name: 'MSIE versions 2010',
                        data: [1, 5, 10, 15],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                y: 21.63,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                    data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                    color: colors[1]
                }
            }, {
                y: 11.94,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                        'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                    data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                    color: colors[2]
                }
            }, {
                y: 7.15,
                color: colors[3],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Safari versions',
                    categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                        'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                    data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                    color: colors[3]
                }
            }, {
                y: 2.14,
                color: colors[4],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Opera versions',
                    categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                    data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                    color: colors[4]
                }
            }];

    function setChart(name, categories, data, color, type) {
        var len = chart.series.length;
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            console.log(chart.series.length);
            chart.series[0].remove();
        }
        console.log('a');
        if(data.series){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.series.length; i ++ ){
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: data.series[i].name,
                    data: data.series[i].data,
                    type: data.series[i].type,
                    color: data.series[i].color || 'white'
                });
            }
        } else {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: name,
                    data: data,
                    type: type,
                    color: color || 'white'
                });
        }
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Click again to view brands.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart(null, drilldown.categories, drilldown, drilldown.type);
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart(name, categories, data, drilldown.type);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y +'%';
                    }
                }
            },
            spline: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            setChart(name, categories, data, 'column');
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: colors[0],
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var point = this.point,
                    s = this.x +':<b>'+ this.y +'% market share</b><br/>';
                if (point.drilldown) {
                    s += 'Click to view '+ point.category +' versions';
                } else {
                    s += 'Click to return to browser brands';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: name,
            data: data,
            color: 'white'
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks @RobSchmuecker, but that's only single series drilldown. I need multiple.

Comment: Two data series each of which has drilldowns.

Comment: So, again, I want each drilldown to go to two series displayed, not one. I'm trying to get the above example to work but am failing. The key example is this: Take continents. Have two datasets you want to display on the same chart, one a line, one in columns. Click on a data point in either series. Get a chart where both datasets are indexed by country, not continent.

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/ clicking on the Series name i.e. `Republican` goes to a new chart with 2 series

Comment: Yes. This is actually what I want. Please post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which has multiple series as drill-downs of multiple series:

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts multi-series drilldown'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click columns to drill down to single series. Click categories to drill down both.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: '2010',
            data: [{
                name: 'Republican',
                y: 5,
                drilldown: 'republican-2010'
            }, {
                name: 'Democrats',
                y: 2,
                drilldown: 'democrats-2010'
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'other-2010'
            }]
        }, {
            name: '2014',
            data: [{
                name: 'Republican',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'republican-2014'
            }, {
                name: 'Democrats',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'democrats-2014'
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'other-2014'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'republican-2010',
                data: [
                    ['East', 4],
                    ['West', 2],
                    ['North', 1],
                    ['South', 4]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'democrats-2010',
                data: [
                    ['East', 6],
                    ['West', 2],
                    ['North', 2],
                    ['South', 4]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'other-2010',
                data: [
                    ['East', 2],
                    ['West', 7],
                    ['North', 3],
                    ['South', 2]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'republican-2014',
                data: [
                    ['East', 2],
                    ['West', 4],
                    ['North', 1],
                    ['South', 7]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'democrats-2014',
                data: [
                    ['East', 4],
                    ['West', 2],
                    ['North', 5],
                    ['South', 3]
                ]
            }, {
                id: 'other-2014',
                data: [
                    ['East', 7],
                    ['West', 8],
                    ['North', 2],
                    ['South', 2]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/